# MS Excel 2007 condition

Tags: excel

My knowledge  when it comes to creating condition and formulas in MS Excel 2007 is limited.
I would like to ask if how I can create solution to this problem:

I have Employment status in column A, its either C (contractual) or R (for regular employee)
then I have job category at column B for the employee position level, for contractual employee(Jr, Mid, Sr) are the choices or  value of the drop down list  and for regular employee the values of the drop list are ( A, B, C).

What I want to happen is when I chose to select or input "C" in Employment status( column A) then I click the column B the choices for the drop down list that should be displayed are Jr, Mid, Sr. and when R is the input value  A, B , C should be displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create named ranges referring to your options in column A.

eg. Create on a new sheet the values `Jr, Mid, Sr` in A1 to A3, then add a named range called `C`.
Do the same for `A, B, C` in B1 to B2 and add a named range `R`.

Finally in the list drop down option enter `=INDIRECT(A1)`, this should refer to the named range you've selected.

You might have to play around with dragging/copying if it's for more than a single cell.

**Edit:** lots of examples and information [**here**](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html).